# how can I make amp-base-carousel show images immediately and work smoothly

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to make a carousel for top news section of a website. In order to achieve that, I use amp-base-carousel component. However, it doesn't seem to work properly as you can see on this test site: https://otoman.net/29/index.html (on mobile/tablet devices)

The following issues are noticeable:

1. Not all images are loaded immediately (as I want) even though I tried to `preload`;
2. Swiping is not smooth as it accidentally jumps over 2 images on just a little faster swipe;
3. It somehow halts at the last image if swipe is too fast; and
4. There's sometimes lagging between swipes (as if it tried to refresh).

Can anybody explain these issues? Is there any way to fix it? If no, is going with Owl-carousel & `amp-script` possible?

My full test code is as follows. The actual page includes `amp-list`.

```
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://otoman.net/29/index.html" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/WyrtHT5/otoman-favicon-03.png">
  <link rel="preload" href="https://i.ibb.co/FK9ZrDP/ezgif-com-gif-maker-51.jpg" as="image">
  <link rel="preload" href="https://i.ibb.co/SK8Q9GR/ezgif-com-gif-maker-49.jpg" as="image">
  <link rel="preload" href="https://i.ibb.co/K71vXzt/ezgif-com-resize-30.jpg" as="image">
  <link rel="preload" href="https://i.ibb.co/CwyzcZw/ezgif-com-gif-maker-42.jpg" as="image">
  <link rel="preload" href="https://i.ibb.co/G0rZ9M7/ezgif-com-gif-maker-38.jpg" as="image">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-base-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-base-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-custom>
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  .hp-img {
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px #f2f2f2;
  }
  .hp-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .hp-container:active {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }
  .hp-container:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <amp-base-carousel dir="ltr" width="100vw" height="68vw" heights="(min-width: 769px) 30.5vw, (min-width: 501px) 38vw, 68vw" layout="responsive" advance-count="1" visible-count="(min-width: 769px) 3.2, (min-width: 501px) 2.5, 1.4" snap-by="1" style="background:transparent" loop="true">
    <div class="hp-container">
      <amp-img class="hp-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/FK9ZrDP/ezgif-com-gif-maker-51.jpg" width="80vw" height="80vw" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    </div>
    <div class="hp-container">
      <amp-img class="hp-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/SK8Q9GR/ezgif-com-gif-maker-49.jpg" width="80vw" height="80vw" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    </div>
    <div class="hp-container">
      <amp-img class="hp-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/K71vXzt/ezgif-com-resize-30.jpg" width="80vw" height="80vw" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    </div>
    <div class="hp-container">
      <amp-img class="hp-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/CwyzcZw/ezgif-com-gif-maker-42.jpg" width="80vw" height="80vw" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    </div>
    <div class="hp-container">
      <amp-img class="hp-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/G0rZ9M7/ezgif-com-gif-maker-38.jpg" width="80vw" height="80vw" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    </div>
  </amp-base-carousel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not seeing the issues you identify (1-4). Are your issues with this subset or with the unpublished full site? For testing, put your list in `<amp-state>` to minimize network latency.

Comment: @JayGray The issues seem to appear only on iOs devices (both with Safari & Chrome). Just had a check on Android devices and identified no problem.